# What Front end framework is used to develop jboss-eap adminstrator console

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, jboss6.x

I am trying to figure out what front-end framework is used to develop the jboss administrator console application. i.e. The one typically accessed via http://localhost:9990/console.

If the source is open, please also assist with a link where one can access it.

Comment: HAL -> https://github.com/hal/core, and maybe can help http://www.dashbuilder.org/

Comment: Thank you so much. Thats exactly what I was looking for.